# C++ Ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, visual-c++, overloading

I have the following code for a "safe" strncpy() -- basically it's wrapper automatically takes fixed array sizes for string buffers so you don't have to do the extra work to pass them in (and this convenience is safer because you won't accidentally type the wrong size for fixed array buffers).

```
inline void MySafeStrncpy(char *strDest,size_t maxsize,const char *strSource)
{
    if(maxsize)
    {
        maxsize--;
        strncpy(strDest,strSource,maxsize);
        strDest[maxsize]=0;
    }
}

inline void MySafeStrncpy(char *strDest,size_t maxDestSize,
    const char *strSource, size_t maxSourceSize)
{
    size_t minSize=(maxDestSize<maxSourceSize) ? maxDestSize:maxSourceSize;
    MySafeStrncpy(strDest,minSize,strSource);
}

template <size_t size>
void MySafeStrncpy(char (&strDest)[size],const char *strSource)
{
    MySafeStrncpy(strDest,size,strSource);
}

template <size_t sizeDest,size_t sizeSource>
void MySafeStrncpy(char (&strDest)[sizeDest],
    const char (&strSource)[sizeSource])
{
    MySafeStrncpy(strDest,sizeDest,strSource,sizeSource);
}

template <size_t sizeSource>
void MySafeStrncpy(char *strDest,size_t maxDestSize,
    const char (&strSource)[sizeSource])
{
    MySafeStrncpy(strDest,maxDestSize,strSource,sizeSource);
}
```

Using the code results in an error in Visual C++ 2008 when compiling:

```
char threadname[16];
MySafeStrncpy(threadname,"MainThread");

error C2668: 'MySafeStrncpy' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
>        could be 'void MySafeStrncpy<16,11>(char (&)[16],const char (&)[11])'
>        or       'void MySafeStrncpy<16>(char (&)[16],const char *)'
>        while trying to match the argument list '(char [16], const char [11])'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

It seems like the compiler is unable to determine if the character string literal `"MainThread"` should be treated as a `const char *` or a `const char[11]` when determining which template function to call.

I would like it to treat the string literal as a `const char[11]` and select the `void MySafeStrncpy<16,11>(char (&)[16],const char (&)[11])` variant since that is the "safest".

Also two more constraints on answers: 1) I am unable to switch compilers (the code compiles on other compilers) and 2) the company will not allow me to use external template libraries for a solution.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear that g++ compiles that :)

Comment: @themel: Thanks for noting that.  I clarified in my Question that it's a problem in Visual C++ 2008.

Comment: FYI, when I discovered overloading (around 1997), I used it a lot and thought how cool/clever it was.  About 5 years ago I almost completely stopped using overloading - yes I now have functions like print1, print2, etc.  Main reason: when I use IDE to search my project, I only get what I am looking for, no need to pick from a long list.

Comment: @radim: The functions are all next to each other and not really at all confusing.  Plus this code apparently compiles fine on some compilers :-(

Answer (score 2):

According to 13.3.3.1.1, *Array-to-pointer conversion* has *Exact Match*
rank, so this function call might be ambiguous in the standard spec.
If you are allowed to change the definition:

```
template <size_t size>
void MySafeStrncpy(char (&strDest)[size],const char *strSource)
```

to:

```
template <size_t size, class T>
void MySafeStrncpy(char (&strDest)[size], T strSource)
```

like [here](http://ideone.com/dofwp),
then probably that'll be the simplest workaround.

Comment: "_Array-to-pointer conversion has Exact Match rank_" It's still a conversion, not an exact match. Since when is no conversion not better than a conversion?

Comment: @curiousguy:
Possibly...
However, _No conversions required_ has the identical _Exact Match_ rank too.
Also, VC8, gcc4.3.4/4.5.1(ideone) Comeau online and LLVM online reported
ambiguity when I tested with simplified code.
The overload resolution rules in C++ are too complicated for my poor brain,
so I hope for language lawyer to explain.

Comment: I am extremely surprised. This has always been the case that [over.ics.rank]/3/1/2 "_Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if_" "_S1 is a proper subsequence of S2_" "**the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence**". It is just elementary std C++ knowledge that the rank _Exact Match_ doesn't mean that the types match exactly. I believe [over.ics.rank] didn't change since the first C++ standard (except for the addition of the `std::initializer_list` stuff obviously).

Comment: @curiousguy: Thanks. Clearly I lack elementary knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

The overloads for char-array/const-char-array and char-array/const-char-pointer can't be distinguished from each other by overload resolution logic (at least the Microsoft logic - this code compiles just fine in GCC. Don't know that the standard says here.). You need to distinguish them in some way, e.g. by renaming the function for arrays or adding a dummy parameter.

An elegant solution would be using boost::enable_if and boost::is_array.

Comment: Let's just say boost is not an option -- it wouldn't fly with the team in a million years if I added boost to the project.  How can I do it elegantly without boost?  I just want it to treat a string constant as an array of chars rather than a char pointer.

Comment: If you can make gcc fly, switch to gcc, but somehow I doubt that :-). Otherwise, you'll have to add some sort of indication that you are working with arrays; MySafeStrncpyPA, MySafeStrncpyAA and MySafeStrncpyAP seem the most straightforward, and I can't think of a better solution.

Comment: Sorry can't switch to GCC either.  Lets just say Visual C++ and no external template libraries are additioanl constraints for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When u are using your function :

```
MySafeStrncpy(threadname,"MainThread");
```

you are not passing the size_t argument in between threadname & "MainThread", but u have defined in function definition.

it shud be something like this :

```
MySafeStrncpy(threadname, sizeof threadname, "MainThread");
```

if u dont want to pass the argument then make it default in ur function definition.

Comment: I want it to call `template <size_t sizeDest,size_t sizeSource>
void MySafeStrncpy(char (&strDest)[sizeDest],
    const char (&strSource)[sizeSource])`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two function overloads for char pointers and char arrays, but you can have two class template specializations:

```
template<typename StringConstant>
class Impl
{
    auto operator()(const StringConstant& str) = delete;
}

template<typename Elem>
[[deprecated("Passing char pointer without length is unsafe")]]
class Impl<const Elem*>
{
    auto operator()(const Elem* str) -> ...
    { ... }
}

template<typename Elem, std::size_t Size>
class Impl<const Elem[Size]>
{
    auto operator()(const Elem str[Size]) -> ...
    {
        // Remember that length of str is Size - 1 (don't include null character)
        ...
    }
}

template<typename StringConstant>
auto func(const StringConstant& str) -> ...
{
    return Impl<StringConstant>()(str);
}

// Need function overload for C arrays.
// When used as rvalue expressions, arrays decay to pointers to the first element.
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9128891/2279059
template<typename Elem, std::size_t Size>
auto func(const Elem(&str)[Size]) -> ...
{
    return Impl<Elem[Size]>()(str);
}
```

Note that you really shouldn't need any of this for anything other than backwards-compatibility. Instead of a constant C character array, just use a `static const` string, and the only reason to accept raw char pointers anywhere is for compatibility with old code or third-party libraries. If you need functions to accept "any kind of string constant", better use `std::basic_string_view`.