# c++ function template specialization for known size typedefed array

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof, template-specialization

Please consider the following code:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <typeinfo>


template< typename Type >
void    func( Type var )
{
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": var = " << var << " [" << typeid( var ).name( ) << "]." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    var is SCALAR. Size = " << sizeof( Type ) << std::endl;
}

#if 1
template< typename Type >
void    func( Type * var )
{
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": var = " << var << " [" << typeid( var ).name( ) << "]." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    var is ARRAY. Size = " << sizeof( Type * ) << std::endl;
}
#endif

int main( )
{
    typedef char    char16[ 16 ];

    char16  c16 = "16 bytes chars.";

    std::cout << "Size of char16 = " << sizeof( char16 ) << std::endl;

    func( c16 );

    return  0;
}
```

If I compile it and run, I see this:

```
> g++ -Wall -g3 spec_f_pointer.cpp -o spec_f_pointer
> ./spec_f_pointer
Size of char16 = 16
func: var = 16 bytes chars. [Pc].
->      var is ARRAY. Size = 8
```

Clearly the `sizeof` printed inside `func` refers to the size of a pointer, and not the size of the `typedef` array, as given in `main()`.

Now I wonder how to correctly do the trick for getting my `func` to specialize in such a way that it correctly knows about my typedef and its size.

Does anyone here can help me, please?

Really thanks.

---

EDIT

Implementing a specialization as:

```
template< typename Type >
void    func( Type * const &var )
{
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": var = " << var << " [" << typeid( var ).name( ) << "]." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    var is ARRAY. Size = " << sizeof( Type * ) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
Size of char16 = 16
func: var = 16 bytes chars. [A16_c].
->      var is SCALAR. Size = 16
```

I noticed the type change from `Pc` to `A16_c`.
Does it help?

Comment: Your approach is just wrong. You take a pointer by reference, which will lose all the information about array size. Why don't you follow my and @David's advice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to specialize your function for arrays, do this:

```
template<typename T, int N>
void func(T(&var)[N])
{
    typedef T Type[N];
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << " [" << typeid( var ).name( ) << "]." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    var is ARRAY. Size = " << sizeof( Type ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of elements: " << N << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of each element: " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: should that be a size_t, not an int?

Comment: @Dave: Doesn't really matter, if you ask me.

Comment: It doesn't... until you have an array where int_max < array size < size_t_max

Comment: This is forcing the user to pass an additional template argument telling the size of data, and it is somewhat redundant and not very error prone. Of course I can wrap it in macros that take the `sizeof` on function call, but, woudn't it be a more elegant approach?

Comment: @Dave: Exactly. That's why I say that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @fljx: You don't force the user to pass anything. Both T and N will be deduced automagically. This is a very elegant approach!

Comment: @fljx You don't have to pass another argument, N is deduced.

Comment: @fljx this does not force the user to pass any template argument, the compiler is able to infer both types from the call. Note that the N is nt a function argument, but part of the type of the single argument to the function, and the function as it is (here or in my answer) is elegant, if not trivial to read for inexperienced programmers. Unlike any macro, this template is type safe and will not be used mistakenly with anything other that an array (compare to the `sizeof arg/sizeof arg[0]` style macro that will silently produced incorrect values for arrays that have already decayed)

Comment: Hmmm... now I got. Sorry, I was really lazy. There is a conceptual difference in what I was trying to see and what you said. Your solution is really correct. Really thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When used as rvalue expressions, arrays decay to pointers to the first element. The function that you have defined takes a *pointer* and does what is expected. If you want to maintain the array as an array you need to pass it by reference, and because the number of elements is part of the type you probably want to use that as another template argument:

```
template <typename T, int N>
void f( T(&arg)[N] ) {
    cout << sizeof arg << endl;
}
```