# know how big an argument is

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

suppose I'm passing an argument to a function like this:

```
void myFunc( int* arrayOfInts );
```

this doesn't seem safe in the sense that the function does not know the size of the array of ints. I can put a comment saying "this function assumes it's getting an array of 10 ints" but it is not possible to check it. So wrong usage of this function can lead to the mysterious "segmentation fault". Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the size of the array as well, C-style:

```
void myFunc(int* arrayOfInts, int arraySize);
```

Or pass in a pointer to after the end of the array, iterator-style:

```
void myFunc(int* begin, int* end);
```

Or pass in a `std::vector<int>` or equivalent and sidestep the problem entirely:

```
void myFunc(const std::vector<int>& vec);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, when dealing with raw arrays, functions generally require that you pass in the size of the array as well, like

```
void foo(int *arr, size_t size_);
```

But in C++, why don't you use `std::vector` anyways? It's safe.

Answer (score 2):

use template function

```
template <int N>
void fmyFunc(int (& array)[N]) 
{ 
}
```

Or STL container(is better way in modern C++ code)

```
void fmyFunc(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
}
```

The old way is to pass in array size

```
void fmyFunc(int* arrayOfInts, int size)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the argument by reference to an array instead, and make the size of the array a template parameter `N`:

```
template <int N>
void myFunc(int (&arrayOfInts)[N])
{
    // here we know the size is N
}
```

Alternatively, if your function should only accept arrays of a certain size (e.g. a 3D-point which is an array of size 3), specify that size instead of using a template. This way the compiler will only let you call this function with a valid array:

```
void myFunc(int (&arrayOfExactlyThreeInts)[3])
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward C++ answer is to use `std::vector`.

Traditional C/C++ answer is to accept array size as an argument as well.

There is a third answer, specific for C++: you can use a function template specialized for array size. *It does not mean you should*. For details, see the accepted answer at [c++ function template specialization for known size typedefed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128780/c-function-template-specialization-for-known-size-typedefed-array).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a second parameter that indicates the size, or even better use an `std::vector<int>` that will allow you to query the size inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the size, or, preferably, use `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, add an argument with the size of the array. The reason for this is so that you can write **one** function for arrays of different sizes. The approach of writing a template function that figures out the size of the array means that you have a different function for each array size that's passed to the template. And, yes, a `vector` carries its own size around, but adds overhead to be able to do that. Sometimes simplest is best.